# Индексатор на typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

В моем классе есть индексатор this[key] = value ну как в словаре. Как сделать геттер и сеттер на индексатор, чтоб на пример key перед тем как получить значение по ключу, перевести в json?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [`Proxy`](https://learn.javascript.ru/proxy):

```js
let _data = {
  key: {value: 42}
}, data = new Proxy(_data, {
  get(target, key){
    if(key in target)
      return JSON.stringify(target[key]);
    else
      return null;
  }
});

console.info(data.key); // {"value":42}
```